# how to call query from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am a beginner in mysql, can you help me to call query from this situation

I have 2 table, and I make id is auto increment

table 1: **closed_route**

```
= id | name | lat 

and the query is =

=1|kenjeran 1|-7.2499|-7.249

=2|mulyosari 2|-7.259|-7.259
```

table 2: 
**user_location**

```
= id | lat | long1 | lat2 | long2
and the query is =

=18|-7.24945|112.783|-7.25907|112.795
```

table 3:
**markers**

```
=id | lat | lng | name
```

what i wanna ask is :
how to insert column in my table 3 using that tables

i use this code but the result is 0 , actually that table have query

```
INSERT INTO markers (lat,lng,name) SELECT user_location.lat, user_location.long1,  closed_route.name
FROM user_location, closed_route
where user_location.lat LIKE CONCAT ('%', closed_route.lat, '%')LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a form of the query that should work:

```
INSERT INTO markers (lat, lng, name)
    SELECT ul.lat, ul.long1, cr.name
    FROM user_location ul cross join
         closed_route cr
    ORDER BY ABS(ul.lat - cr.lat)
    LIMIT 1;
```

This will insert a marker with the name of the `closed_route` that has the nearest `lat` value.

Notes:

- This query uses an explicit `join`.  Just don't use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.
- The tables have aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.
- There is no use of `like` on numeric values.  Instead, use numeric functions.
- This may not do what you want, but it seems like a reasonable query.

Comment: thank you so much it`s work just a litlle wrong in ORDER BY ABS(ul.lat - cl.lat) it must be ORDER BY ABS(ul.lat - cr.lat)